# Upgrading MovbableType to 4.32 creates a javascript error with custom fields and kills FCKeditor

Tags: fckeditor, movabletype, movable

Has anyone run into this issue before?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: custom_fields is not defined
```

Then MT generates this in the document:

```
customizable_fields.push('customfield_start_date');
default_fields.push('customfield_start_date');
custom_fields.push('customfield_start_date'); ### ERROR HERE

customizable_fields.push('customfield_end_date');
default_fields.push('customfield_end_date');
custom_fields.push('customfield_end_date');
```

On page load I get an alert from FCKeditor that says

```
Error: The TEXTAREA with id or name set to "editor-content-textarea" was not found
```

The textarea doesn't even exist in the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Needs more detail: I know of at least three FCKEditor plugins for 4.x(and frankly I'm not sure any of them are being actively supported); which exactly are you using? You upgraded to MT4.32 from what? (Is there a reason you didn't upgrade to the actual current 4.x version?) #editor-content-textarea is big text area for the Body field. You don't see that at all? You may have another problem altogether if so.

Comment: We ended up solving this by upgrading to MT5. Still no idea what the real issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Movable Type up to and including 4.31 had problems with entry metadata management.  If you happened to have deleted a custom field at some point in the management of your Movable Type instance, that caused problems in a number of places in the CMS and in the publishing process.  This is discussed in the following documents:

http://bugs.movabletype.org/default.asp?102303
http://code.sixapart.com/trac/movabletype/changeset/4435
http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/release-notes/432.html

If this was your original problem, upgrading to MT 5.x should have solved it.

The initial question talks about upgrading Movable Type to Movable Type 4.32.  It isn't clear what the previous version of Movable Type was.  That bit of information may also have been significant to the original problem.